# Performance difference between function declarations vs function expressions

Tags: javascript, performance

What is the best way to structure your js for performance speed as well as page load speed, less strain on the browser.

```
var myFunc = function(){/*do stuff*/}
```

or

```
function myFunc(){/*do stuff*/}
```

Comment: The two forms you mentioned have no effect on performance whatsoever.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in performance between these two methods.

```
var myFunc = function(){/*do stuff*/}

or

function myFunc(){/*do stuff*/}
```

However the first function is created only when the line is executed. But the second function is available even when the script starts to execute.

It is important to understand [Javascript Hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) to explain this behavior.

[Here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting) is another useful article on this.

Comment: to what I am seeing, Honestly it would be best to claim each function as a var.  But honestly this really does not sound correct.

When I step through the code I see the vars initialize.  Even know the function is not being executed.  Seems like this would take up more memory.

Second link was helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: //Seems like this would take up more memory - Please support this by the details of your observation.